# Запятая перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

В каких случаях нужно ставить запятую перед союзом "как"?

Comment: Такой мужчина как Вы.....?(нужно ли ставить запятую?)


Comment: Конечно, нужно. На необходимость запятой указывает местоимений "такой".

Comment: Нужна ли запятая : "Говорите всем _ как вы их любите" ?

Comment: Да, нужна. *"Как вы их любите"* — придаточная часть со своей грамматической основой, соединяющаяся с главной подчинительным союзом *"как"*.

Comment: А в случае: "Мы переживаем, как ты там?"
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запятая перед союзом "как" ставится в трех случаях.

1. Если "как" является частью вводного оборота ("как правило", "как обычно" и т.д.).
   Пример: *Я, как правило, читаю книгу перед сном.*
2. Если "как" используется в сравнительном обороте.
   Пример: *"Он был надежен, как скала"*
3. Если "как" разделяет части сложного предложения.
   Пример: *"Он внимательно наблюдал за тем, как разворачиваются события"*

Comment: Запятая перед "как" ставится в 6 случаях (https://best-language.ru/zapjataja-pered-kak-stavitsja)

Answer (score 5):

Нужно различать следующие случаи: Все знали его как хорошего рыболова. /знали в качестве кого? в каком качестве?/ запятыми не выделяется. Петров, как хороший работник, был премирован. /по какой причине?/причина - запятыми выделяется.

Answer (score 2):

> Запятая перед "как" ставится в 6 случаях
>   1.В сочетаниях «не кто иной, как» » не что иное, как» Запятая ставится обязательно
>   Примеры: Не кто иной, как мой товарищ.
>   2.Указательные слова: так, такой, такие, тот
>   Примеры: Так красиво, как в прошлый раз, ей станцевать не удалось.
>   3.Перед сочетанием «как и» запятая ставится всегда
>   Примеры: В комнате, как и во всём доме, было уютно.
>   4.Всегда обособляется «как один» «как правило»
>   Примеры: Все, как один, встали на его защиту
>   5. Если в предложении есть значение причины, то из одной его части можно составить вопрос, а из другой - ответ.
>   Примеры: Пётр, как лучший охотник, был выбран старшим.(Почему Пётр был выбран старшим? Потому что он лучший охотник.)
>   6.Сравнение
>   Примеры: Она прекрасна, как роза.

(https://best-language.ru/zapjataja-pered-kak-stavitsja)

Comment: Я скопировал эту информацию из ответа, данного @РиммаМихайлова (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437528/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba)