# Нужно ли здесь выделять оборот с союзом "как"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

*Больше всего денег пойдет на госслужащих, как на самую многочисленную категорию трудящихся, – 14,7 млрд рублей.*
Здесь нужно выделять оборот с союзом "как" или нет? Это больше уточнение (тогда можно поставить запятую) или тут "как" в значении "в качестве" (тогда не нужна)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оборот, являясь приложением, имеет оттенок причинного значения. Его можно заменить придаточным предложением с союзами **поскольку, так как, потому что**.

*Больше всего денег пойдет на госслужащих* [почему? по какой причине?], *потому что они самая многочисленная категория трудящихся.*

Запятая перед тире нужна, т. к. предложение оборотом не заканчивается.
[**Запятая перед "как"**](https://best-language.ru/zapjataja-pered-kak-stavitsja)

**Больше всего денег пойдет на госслужащих, как на самую многочисленную категорию трудящихся, – 14,7 млрд рублей.**

P.S. По поводу "многочисленности": мы ведь не знаем, о какой сфере деятельности идет речь. Если эти люди — налоговики, специалисты пенсионного фонда или таможни (собственно, работники только государственных структур, а не всей России), то смысл предложения правилен.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В тексте речь о зарплатах таможенников.

Answer (score -1):

Давайте разберёмся. Здесь возможны оба варианта:

1. Если в предложении госслужащие - самая многочисленная категория трудящихся, то запятая перед как не нужна. Также не должно быть запятой перед тире.
2. Если в предложении госслужащие получают столько же, сколько и самая многочисленная категория трудящихся, тогда запятая нужна.

Все зависит от того, какой смысл несет предложение.  Я бы выбрал второй вариант, так как госслужащие не могут быть самой многочисленной категорией трудящихся в России. Это просто невозможно. Поэтому советую выбрать вариант с запятой.

Comment: Если бы автор хотел сравнить госслужащих с некоей другой категорией, он бы сформулировал предложение иначе.