# «Надёжен как скала» — нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли запятая в сравнениях вида **надёжен как скала**?

Мне отчего-то кажется, что не нужна, но какое должно быть правило для объяснения — не могу понять.

Comment: Какой же это дубликат, РАЗВЕ МОЖНО ЗАКРЫВАТЬ ТАКИЕ ВОПРОСЫ? Вот только что прочитала эту тему у Розенталя, где он неоднократно повторяет, что решение может быть неоднозначным, что нужно отличать языковую метафору (фразеологический оборот) от художественной и что  выбор может быть авторским и зависит от контекста. Любое предложение индивидуально, а сравнительный оборот - это ИНДИВИДУАЛЬНОСТЬ всегда.  В текстах можно увидеть разные решения для этого конкретного сочетания, поэтому требуется учесть влияние ряда факторов.

Comment: @Sharon Готовы дать альтернативный ответ? Если да - давайте переоткроем.

Comment: Я могу ответить чуть позже, может быть завтра. Но и без меня люди могут дать более содержательный ответ, чем тот, который был принят.

Comment: Пожалуйста, откройте вопрос, я дам на него ответ

Comment: @Sharon Я проголосовал за открытие, сейчас есть только 2 голоса из пяти необходимых для полного открытия. Надо немного подождать, пока наберутся ещё голоса.

Comment: А К, странная у Вас позиция. Вы задали вопрос. Получили на него ответ — без какого-либо обоснования, просто со ссылкой на чужой ответ. Вы оценили и приняли этот "новый" ответ. А потом первым проголосовали за его закрытие — как дубликат. Честное слово, я ничего не понимаю! Но за переоткрытие проголосовала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тема касается  **фразеологических оборотов с союзом КАК**

**Общая теория**

***Твердый  как камень, надежный  как скала…*** Розенталь рассматривает обособление фразеологических (устойчивых) оборотов в отдельной теме. Фразеологический оборот   он называет **сравнением языкового вида.**

***Надежный как скала*** – это ***очень надежный,*** оборот обозначает степень признака и в предложении является обстоятельством. Розенталь  приводит **список** наиболее распространенных оборотов, составленный по данным словарей и по наблюдениям над текстами  различного жанра, но список этот неполный и может быть продолжен.

Интересно то, что **обособление фразеологического оборота также возможно,** при этом он становится не языковой, **а художественной метафорой** (также его можно назвать оборотом со значением уподобления, сравнительным оборотом, попутным сравнением). Обычно при обособлении что-то меняется  (например, позиция оборота или его состав),  в то же время автор может обособить  и обычный фразеологический оборот. **Этот материал подробно можно посмотреть у Розенталя** (п. 4.6): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

**Как же сделать правильный выбор?** Один из самых простых методов – это структурно-интонационный анализ. Надо понимать, что **на оборот всегда падает ударение,**  а вот определяемое слово становится ударным только при обособлении, сравнить: ***надЁжный, как скалА*** и ***надежный как скалА.***

**Решение задачи**

Оборот ***как скала*** может относиться к разным прилагательным (***серый, неприступный, твердый, надежный***), поэтому оборот  чаще бывает не языковой, а художественной метафорой (сравнительным оборотом)  и **поэтому обособляется.**

**Но предложения с необособленным оборотом также встречаются** (в таких случаях  структура предложения такова, что логическое ударение удобно сделать только на обороте).

Примеры с оборотом ***как скала***

(1) ― Ты **надЁжен, как скалА.** Так и хочется к тебе прислониться!

Олег оказался очень интересным человеком, к тому же порядочным и **надЁжным, как скалА.**

При этом он прост, всегда весел  в самых трудных обстоятельствах и **надЁжен, как скалА.**

(2) Лицо его продолжало оставаться **непроницаемым как скалА**.

Он занял половину порта, **серый как скалА**.

Такой суровый Баев, **неприступный как скалА,** и на тебе — семейный очаг...

Answer (score 1):

[mark as duplicate](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/15/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA), [#, пункт 2](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/16/193695):

Да, она ставится!

> Если "как" используется в сравнительном обороте. Пример: "Он был надежен, как скала