# Нужна ли запятая перед "как от выстрела"?

Tags: запятые

Она дернулась, как от выстрела, и в животе образовалась дыра.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая нужна. "*Как от выстрела*" — явный сравнительный оборот.

О пунктуации при сравнительных оборотах (в частности, о запятой перед "*как*") можно прочитать [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147,3).

На этом сайте есть ответы на вопрос [Запятая перед "как"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/15/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA).